# What is the general term for a persistent/ongoing magical effect in D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, magic, terminology

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate word to describe a magical effect of unknown origin in a D&D game. I can't call it a spell or spell effect since it's not known whether the effect is caused by a spell or some other kind of magic. The most obvious term that comes to mind is "enchantment", but in the context of D&D, this term is reserved specifically for magic that affects the minds of others, so it is not suitable as a general term for any magical effect. So what would an appropriate term be for a persistent magical effect?

Comment: Ryan, are you talking about a specific edition of D&D, or are you looking for a term that spans multiple/all editions?

Comment: I happen to be playing 5th edition, but the question seemed general enough to me that it hadn't occurred to me that the answer might depend on the edition. I suppose, if your answer is limited to a specific edition, just indicate that in the answer.

Comment: The question about terminology may be generic enough but it is a slippery slope as 3.X/PF and 5E treat how dispel magic affect them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly searching for a synonym/alternative, I think 'magical effect' itself is appropriate- it covers both spell and non-spell cases. In addition, several game elements (in 5e, at least) refer to them as such:

[Dispel Magic:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic)

> Choose one creature, object, or **magical effect** within range. [...]

[Antimagic Field:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)

> Spells and other **magical effects**, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere.
>
> [...]
>
> Spells and other **magical effects**, such as magic missile and charm person, that target a creature or an object in the sphere have no effect on that target.

[Nystul's/Arcanist's Magic Aura:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura)

> You change the way the target appears to spells and **magical effects** [...]

Comment: Yep, "magical effect" is indeed the general D&D (5e) term for effects caused by magic (whether or not the source is a spell).

Comment: Ok, it looks like this is indeed the term used in official materials.

Answer (score 1):

**Permanent Enchantment**

Enchantment has two meanings in D&D.

The narrow one is a mind affecting spell.

The more common meaning is magic imbued in an object or creature.  A magic sword has an enchantment on it.  You could even say that the narrow meaning is just a specific case of the broader meaning because the mind affecting spell is a spell that imbues a creature with an effect for a specific amount of time.

For the other part of your question, "permanent" is the term for a spell that does not have an end point to its duration but is ongoing.  This is different from an Instant spell that makes a change to an object where the change is then permanent (the damage from a fireball persists after the spell and cannot be dispelled).

Answer (score -3):

I would refer to it based on how the effect manifests itself. For example you could call it a dome, cloud, haze, mist, field, emanation, or any other more specific or appropriate adjective.

Comment: The querent is not looking for ways to describe magical effects, but ways to refer to magical effects with no need for context.